# How will 'fopen' interpret a 'char[]' whose capacity is larger than the string it contains?

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, c-strings

I am writing a program which can encrypt a text file.

First I need to ask the users for the file name. I did something like:

```
char file_name[50];
fgets(file_name, 50, stdin);
```

but it didn't work. How can I do this?

I am confused that if I store the file name in an char array which has, say, 50 elements, but the file name has just 10 characters. When I pass the array or the pointer to `fopen`, what is the program going to do with the remaining 40 elements of that array?  Are they storing any value? Will they be passed to `fopen`?

Answer (score 2):

In C, a string is just a `\0` terminated sequence of characters. So long as there is a `\0` within the 50 bytes of `file_name`, `file_name` contains a valid string for `fopen()`.

The reason `fopen()` probably failed is that the name you passed it had an extra `\n` in it after reading it from the input. This is because `fgets()` also stores the newline character into the buffer. You have to remove it before using the string as a file name.

```
char *p = strrchr(file_name, '\n');
if (p) *p = '\0';
```

Comment: This is true, but it wasn't the question.

Comment: @H2CO3, thanks, I was explaining why `fopen()` didn't work. I also added an explanation about a string.

Comment: @jxh...He is asking for user input file name... Can we do it like that... fprintf(stdout,"%s",__file__);... is it right method to ask a user for a file name and then pass it to fopen function?

Comment: @Krishna: That's what the question title says, but reading the question description, he's wondering how `fopen()` treats the string.

Answer (score 1):

> i am confused that if i store the file name in an char array which, say, has 50 elements. but the file name has just 10 characters. when i pass the array or the pointer to fopen() function, what is the program gonna do with the rest 40 elements of that array?

You mean the rest 38, right? The 11th character will be the newline `fgets()` puts into the buffer, and the 12th one is assigned a NUL (`'\0'`) character.

It isn't going to do anything with the rest.

> Are they storing any value? will they be passed to fopen()?

Obviously, they are storing **some** value, which is indeterminate and irrelevant anyway. No, they won't be passed to `fopen()`. In fact, none of the characters will be passed to `fopen()`. When you use the array as the argument of a function, it automatically **decays into a pointer to its first element,** and it's only that pointer that `fopen()` sees.

Internally, `fopen()` is most likely implemented using the `open()` system call (on Unices, at least), and, as almost every function accepting a C string, it will interpret the pointer by searching for the NUL-terminator and assuming that the file name is made of characters up to (but not including) that `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` will check the string character by character until it encounters `\0`, and then it stops. So the rest of the string you get from `fgets` won't matter, as long as the first 10 characters plus the trailing `\0` make a valid string.

Also note that you need to remove the extra `\n` from the string you get from `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are just characters in memory followed by a null byte. For example:

```
'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' ',' ' ' 'w' 'o' 'r' 'l' 'd' '!' '\0'
48  65  6C  6C  6F  2C  20  77  6F  72  6C  64  21   00
```

When you pass an array to the filename argument of `fopen`, it decays into a pointer. Essentially, what `fopen` will do is it will use the characters up to and excluding the null byte. Anything after that isn't touched.